# Form validation on Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seem to have a problem with this function which is used in a contact form. This form was made by a developper
I get this message displaying in a random way : "An Error Occured.."  when I click Submit button in my form. Most of time I get this error message but on local I yesterday got it not displayed and bassed to the next step and validated the form. Problem is I was not able to reproduce it.

I found the controler use a PostIndex function as follow

```
    public function postIndex($origin = '')
{
    $input = Input::only('title','name','country_id','company','company_website','phone_number','email','message');
    $input['origin'] = $origin;
    $input['ip'] = getIP();
    // Create a new validator instance from our validation rules
    $validator = Validator::make($input, ContactUs::$rules );

    // If validation fails, we'll exit the operation now.
    if ($validator->fails())
        return Redirect::route('contact-us')->withErrors($validator);
    try {
        $contact = ContactUs::create($input);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('error', 'An Error Occured..');  
    }
    return Redirect::route('contact-us.show',$contact->token)->with('success', 'We have received your message.');

}
```

I suppose there is an issue with the validator  relatd to rules which are defined as follow

```
public static $rules = array(
        'title'             => 'required',
        'name'              => 'required',
        'email'             => 'required|email',
        'country_id'        => 'required|exists:countries,id',
        'company'           => 'required',
        'company_website'   => 'required',
        'phone_number'      => 'required',
        'message'           => 'required',
    );
```

This is the form field:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 " for="title">Title: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {{Form::select("title",array("Mr"=>"Mr","Ms"=>"Ms","Mrs"=>"Mrs"), 'Mr' ,array("class"=>"form-control"))}}

                        {{ $errors->first('title', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="name">Name: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control required {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'error' : '' }}"
                               name="name" id="name" value="" required>
                        {{ $errors->first('name', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="email">Email: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control required {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'error' : '' }}"
                               name="email" id="email" value="" required>
                        {{ $errors->first('name', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('country_id') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="country_id">Country: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        {{ Form::select('country_id',  [''=>'-- Select Country --'] + Country::lists('name', 'id') ,'',array("class"=>"form-control","id"=>"country_id","required"=>"required")) }}
                        {{ $errors->first('country_id', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('company') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="company">Company Name: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control required {{ $errors->has('company') ? 'error' : '' }}" required name="company" id="company" value="">
                        {{ $errors->first('company', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('company_website') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="company_website">Company Website: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="url" class="form-control required {{ $errors->has('company_website') ? 'error' : '' }}" required name="company_website" id="company_website" value="">
                        {{ $errors->first('company', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('phone_number') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="phone_number">Phone Number: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control hidden " name="phone_number" id="phone_number" placeholder="in internal format e.g : +185523232422" value="">
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control">
                        <div id="valid-msg" class="hide text-aqc-green val_msg">✓ Valid</div>
                        <div id="error-msg" class="hide text-aqc-red val_msg">Invalid number</div>
                        {{ $errors->first('phone_number', '<label class="error">:message</label>') }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('message') ? 'error' : '' }}">
                    <label class="col-lg-3" for="message">Your Message: <sup>*</sup></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" style="min-height:150px;max-height:200px;" placeholder="Place Your Message Here" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Routes are defined as follow

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'guest'), function() {
  Route::get('contact-us',array('as' => 'contact-us', 'uses' => 'ContactUsController@contactRedirect'));
  Route::get('contact-us/{origin}', array('as' => 'contact-us', 'uses' => 'ContactUsController@getIndex'));
  Route::post('contact-us/{origin}', 'ContactUsController@postIndex');
  Route::get('contact-us/{token}/show', array('as' => 'contact-us.show', 'uses' => 'ContactUsController@showDetail'));
  Route::post('contact-us/{token}/show', array('as' => 'contact-us.show.post', 'uses' => 'ContactUsController@postDetail'));

  Route::post('contact-us/{token}/message', array('as' => 'contact-us.message.post', 'uses' => 'ContactUsController@postMessage'));

  Route::get('blog/{postSlug}', array('as' => 'view-post', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getView'));
  Route::post('blog/{postSlug}', 'BlogController@postView');

  Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'FrontEndController@getIndex'));
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with entering data into your database. Remove the try/catch block and provide us with actual error that is happening, or just `var_dump()` the `$e` variable in your catch block.

Comment: this is what I get when remove the try catch block : ErrorException in ContactUsController.php line 40:
Undefined variable: contact
in ContactUsController.php line 40
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined variable: contact'

so based on my understanding there is a problem with the token , am I correct ?

Comment: Hm, my best bet is to put success return statement inside try block, after `$contact` is created

Comment: I have seen this form working in the past and yesterday. I believe there is another reason that code to prevent it working.  may be a session or token issue...
    just for information this is how the routes are defined Route::group(array('prefix' => 'contact-us'), function() {
        Route::get('/', array('as' => 'admin.contact-us', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\Contact\ContactUsController@getContactRequests'));
        Route::get('/{token}', array('as' => 'admin.contact-us.show', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\Contact\ContactUsController@showContactRequest'));

Comment: Try and use `fill` instead of `create` on your ContactUs model. You need to define fillable attributes in your model like this `protected $fillable = [....]`. That may solve it

Comment: @lyyka I have tried but not working better

Comment: I success to dd the validator but I don't know what I should look at.. any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
My contact form was trying to geoip the ip of the submitter but the database of geoip was missing in my laravel due to migration..